# Load JTable with data from ArrayList<HashMap>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, hashmap, jpanel

I'm trying to let a JTable load from data stored in a ArrayList with HashMaps. The code looks something like

```
private ArrayList<HashMap> menuLijst;
private JPanel tablePanel;
//some init
tablePanel = new JPanel();
```

then, this is some random data, just to make sure it works.

```
this.menuList = new ArrayList();
// hashmap
HashMap hm1 = new HashMap();
HashMap hm2 = new HashMap();
hm1.put("question", "Contact");
hm1.put("query", "select contact from tim");
hm1.put("message", "contact");
hm2.put("question", "Sales");
hm2.put("query", "select sales from tim");
hm2.put("message", "sales");
menuList.add(hm1);
menuList.add(hm2);
```

so that's how my HashMap looks like, which is kind of superfluous to know, since the JTabel does not depend on pre-defined size-data.

All together, my question is, how to put data from the ArrayLists with HashMaps in the JTable.

I have tried some options but it didn't work out as it should be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to use the comment of Dacwe but in the meantime he deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you just create your own `TableModel` implementation (or extend from one of the available classes), or you must use another data structure (see the available constructors on `DefaultTableModel`).

But creating your `TableModel` would be rather straight-forward with this data structure as soon as you find a mechanism to determine the column order as a `HashMap` as no ordering.

The [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) contains a section on creating `TableModel` instances

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and implement the following methods:

- getColumnCount
- getRowCount
- getValueAt
- getColumnName

Choose the order of appearance of the columns (for example query then message), and use

```
HashMap map = menuLijst.get(row);
if (col==0)
     return map.get("query");
else if (col==1)
     return map.get("message");
```

to implement  `getValueAt(int row, int col)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i took it another way around. But still thanks

Answer (score 0):

jtable uses the javabeans concept, and hashmap key/value pair are not implemented as javabeans property. I would use a pair class or define your own pair class with key/value property